# In Emacs, what's the opposite of invisible text?

Tags: elisp

You can't see invisible text in the buffer, but if you save the file, it'll be there. I want the oppsoite -- something to display, but if I save the file it won't be written to disk.

In particular I want to display an ellipsis (the "..." symbol) where I have hidden text.

In case it's relevant, [here's the code](https://github.com/JeffreyBenjaminBrown/play/blob/d8d53c659e9b2bd90454ed2fadd0e25239c5bb1d/dot-emacs.el#L16-L53) where I'd like to do that. The "fold" function hides text, and the "unfold" function shows it again. The region folded or unfolded is every line just below the current one with more leading space than the current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `invisible` property to a custom symbol `my-fold`:

```el
(put-text-property startRegion endRegion 'invisible
                   (if toHide 'my-fold nil))
```

You can say that `my-fold` invisibility should use an ellipsis:

```el
;; Cause use of ellipses for invisible text.
(add-to-invisibility-spec '(my-fold . t))
```

---

Further reading:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Invisible Text`
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Replacing Specs`

Comment: It works! Do I understand correctly, then, that invisible text can *only* be represented with an ellipsis, not any arbitrary symbol?

Comment: For this particular method using `buffer-invisibility-spec` that seems to be the case.  For the arbitrary "replacing specs" you could display anything you like.